# Running system process in java so it won't freeze the program

Tags: java, process

Please show me how i should correctly execute system proccess in java. I would like to do kinfd of console in java. I've made sth what looks like that.

[image]

How should I correctly invoke the process put in JTextField?
***I know how to use listeners etc. I am only asking about running the process correctly.***  Thank You : ) But i would like to ensure that the whole layout will not freeze.

Comment: Where's your code? How are you invoking the process?

Comment: You only need to worry about freezing the UI if you have long-running operations running on the UI thread. You are creating a new *process*, so you do not need to worry about it interfering with the operation of your own process. (All this assumes you do not wait for the process to end on the UI thread; if you do, then you'll freeze up.)

Comment: @dlev depends on whether he wants to wait for the results from executing the process, which he probably does if it's user-initiated.  Whichever thread calls Process.waitFor() will block until it's complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SwingWorker and put the action in the background.  Do a Runtime.exec() with the contents in the background thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html